# Move user to a different org

Tags: user, migration, org

I have created a developer org and added my manager as a user to show him the capabilities of Salesforce and show him the customizations I had made.

He now has been added to different communities using this account and want this user to be moved to our production environment. What is the best approach to achieve this?

I know I can change his login and create a new user in the production org, but I am afraid he will lose his trailhead progression, the communities he has been added to etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, user in Production is required to be created manually, and then all the user permission should be same as Sandbox.

Ideally Trailhead should be used from a personal Developer org instead of a company sandbox.